# PHP/MYSQL Year Month table for news archive

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, archive

I am creating a news archive for my site and want to create an overview page from the following DB table:

```
id - Unique identifier
newsDate - in a format XXXX-XX-XX
title - News Item title
details - News item
photo - News Item Photo
caption - News Item Photo caption
update - Timestamp for record
```

The news on the site is current but I hope to add some data from years gone by over the next few months and years.

What I want to do is create a new line for each year and highlight the month which corresponds to a record in the DB table, similar to that below.

```
2002 JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC
2004 JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC
2005 JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC
2008 JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC
```

Any help or advice would be much appreciated

Comment: Why not import them like they were regular news articles being created?

Answer (score 0):

Stick with the table layout you've got, then for the overview page select newsDate as year and month and group by that (possibly with count if you want to show how many articles there are in each month), then iterate through it for you lines. Should be fairly basic to do

Answer (score 0):

**TEST Full Example**

**CSS**

```
#Decor 
{
    width:200px;
}

#Decor, #Decor ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left:25px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    padding-left:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.handle { 
    background: transparent url( /images/tree-handle.png ) no-repeat left top; 
    display:block; 
    float:left;
    width:10px; 
    height:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.closed { background-position: left top; }
.opened { background-position: left -10px; }
```

**PHP File**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link href="CSS/treeview.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            //start the tree in an autocollapsed state
            $('#Decor ul').hide(400);

            $('#Decor li').on('click', function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation(); // prevent links from toggling the nodes
                $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
            });

            // This code opens all hyperlinks in a new window 
            // and avoids anchors
            $('#Decor a').not('[href="#"]').attr('target', '_blank');
        });
    </script>
</head>

<?php
define("DB_USER","");
define("DB_PASS","");
define("DB_HOST","");
define("DB_NAME","");

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) or die(mysqli_errno());
$s="SELECT *,content_id,COUNT(content_id) AS itemCount FROM content_mast GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date_upload,'%Y') DESC";
$sql_result=mysqli_query($link,$s);
?>
<ul id="Decor">
<?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_result))
    {
    $datetime=strtotime($row['date_upload']);
    $tday = date("Y", $datetime);
    $count = $row['itemCount'];
    ?>
     <li class="level1"><?php echo "<u><strong>{$tday} ({$count})</strong></u><br>"; ?>
    <?php
        $s1="select * from content_mast where DATE_FORMAT(date_upload,'%Y')=$tday";
        $q=mysqli_query($link,$s1);
        while($month=mysqli_fetch_row($q))
        {
        ?>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="test.php?date=<?php echo $month[5]; ?>"><?php echo date("F",strtotime($month[5])); ?></a></li>
            </ul>
            <?php
        }
    echo "<br>";
    }
?>
</ul>
</html>
```